# What is the relation between Chebyshev Norm and L1 norm in $D$ dimensions

Tags: normed-spaces

How do you translate one to the other (Chebyshev norm to the L1 norm) for $D$ dimensions?

Comment: Or are you looking to find a $d$ times $d$ matrix, $A$, such that $\|Ax\|_\infty = \|x\|_1$?  That is not possible if $d \ge 3$, but that is a little harder than the question I answered.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot convert one to the other.  For some vectors in $d$-dimensions the Chebyshev norm (that is, the $\ell^\infty$ norm) and $\ell^1$ are identical.  For other vector they can differ by up to a factor of $d$.  The best you can say in $d$-dimensions is
$$ \|x\|_\infty \le \|x\|_1 \le d \|x\|_\infty .$$

Comment: Thanks. Here is the context of the problem. I have n datapoints $x_1 \ dots x_n$, where $x_i \in R^d$. I want to minimize the distance where distance uses $L_{\infty}$. I was told to try and relate this problem to minimizing the absolute sum of deviations.

Comment: The only relationship between $L_1$ and $L_\infty$ I can even conceive of is via duality.  And I don't immediately see how to make this work.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/708550/find-formula-for-computing-the-mean-using-different-distance-metrics Here is why I'm asking